# Add "active" class in blade depending on current translated Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Using the package [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) in Laravel 5.1 I managed to localize my site and also to translate the routes. The problem is now the following: How can I add a custom class "active" via blade template depending on the current route?

I have tried so far using HTML::macro but it seems the package [laravelcollective/html](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html): "5.1.*" isn't fully compatible (especially macros) with L5.1.

Even if I would manage to use an macro I can not use the `Request::is('about')` because the routes are translated. I'm pretty sure here has to be an easy approach...

```
Example routes:
www.sitename.com/en/about = www.sitename.com/ro/despre => route to same controller/action
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this!

```
<li class="@if (Request::is('/')) {{'active'}} @endif"><a href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>    
<li class="@if (Request::is('about')) {{'active'}} @endif"><a href="{{URL::to('/about')}}">About</a></li>
<li class="@if (Request::is('contact')) {{'active'}} @endif"><a href="{{URL::to('/contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

With inspiring help from @keithm and from [here](http://blog.legacyteam.info/2015/07/laravel-blade-directive-for-conditional-html-classes/) I did the following:

First extend blade with a new directive, built directly in the AppServiceProvider.php

```
Blade::directive('activeState', function($expression) {
    return '<?php echo activeClass('. $expression . '); ?>';
});
```

Then in your helpers file (if you don't have one you can create it into app/Http/helpers.php) add the following

```
function activeClass($url) {
    return Request::url() == $url ? 'active' : '';
}
```

In blade directly use then the following directive:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('front.portfolio.index') }}" class="nav-block @activeState(URL::route('front.portfolio.index'))">
```

Comment: In your **activeClass** helper function,                                                            `  Request::url() == $url  `                                                                               will mean you have to pass in the full url path; It cannot match url portions. I modified the marching to only match the end of the url:                                 `  ends_with(Request::url(), $url) ? 'active' : '';  `

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question but is this what you're looking for?

```
<span class="someClass @if (Request::url('/myurl') active @endif"></span>
```

Sorry missed that part of the question :).

I didn't test it this way but it should work:

```
@if (Request::url($variable or $pattern .'/restofuri')
```

Comment: Not exactly. If I have 20 languages I would have to build 20 @if-else statements. @ if (Request::url('/myurl-en') active @ elseif (Request::url('/myurl-ro') active @ elseif (Request::url('/myurl-de') active endif

Making a regexp isn't either a solution because the url can differ entirely (see examples from question)

Comment: Cannot find much info from the package repo but I assume that the user's local is either saved in session, config, database or more than place. If the user's setting is saved in db or session you can get it from the view and concatenate the url.

Comment: That doesn't either fix the problem because the "pattern" isn't the same. I edited the question, maybe it makes more sense. But I'll will try to force route on the if-check the current route to a custom locale, eg. "en", so that every time I make the check I will check against "en"... Not very pretty though

Comment: Hi Tudor, I know what you mean but I don't which part you need to know. You can name a route and a function that checks the variables is from the list of locals in config, you can also easily get the translated text from the package you're using. The best way is to get the selected local so you don't have to loop through all the available translations.  I mean variable and /or pattern. Are you saving the user's local or just getting it from URI everytime?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but i also had the same issue and solved it with the laravel helper function `url()->current()` and the localization package helper function `localizeURL`

```
<a href="{{LaravelLocalization::localizeURL(trans('routes.my-route'))}}"
   class="{{(url()->current() == LaravelLocalization::localizeURL(trans('routes.my-route'))) ? "active" : "" }}">
   {{trans('navigation.my-route')}}</a>
```